# Laravel - automatically initialize classes from array, polymorphic relation, cast models to different objects back and forth

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, ioc-container

I need to build a small package to manage model settings in my Laravel app, my main requirment is that they need to be relational, be in its own table. Json fields etc are not allowed.

There is many models which can own some settings. Also, each model can be in different context which means, one model, depending on its "type" field contain diffrent set of settings, and inherits some of them.

### Introduction

Now, some pseudo code to ilustrate this case for you.

```
class Setting extends Model
{
    // polymorphic table
    // properties: id, settingable_id, settingable_type, name, value, type
}

class Project extends Model
{
    // has enum column `type`
    // type can be schoolProject, workProject (2, 3, 10, number of types doesn't matter)
    //
    public function settings()
    {
        return $this->morpMany(Setting::class);
    }
}
```

Okay, as each setting has it type, which basically describe what type and format of data it accepts, I created few classes to reflect that, like that:

```
class BoolSettingType implements SettingInterface
{
    private $name;
    
    public function getValue(): bool
    {
        ...
    }
    
    public function setValue(bool $value): void
    {
        ...
    }
    
    // prepare array for later $model->fill(SettingInterface::serialize())
    public static function seriaize(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'type' => 'bool',
            'value' => $this->getValue()
        ];
    }
}
```

I also added some method to Project model to create a `SettingCollection` containing models transformed to proper SettingTypes (simple factory take care of that).

### The real question

List of settings is predefined – where and how can I define them? What would be the cleanest way?

I mean, lets say we have three settings:

- ProjectIsEditableByUsers (bool)
- UsersCanAddCommentsToProject (bool)
- UsersCanAddMediaToProject (bool)

And... as I wrote above: schoolProject need setting 1 and setting 2, workProject needs setting 2 and 3.

How should I define these settings, get them names, default values, maybe some validator. I thought about making each setting a separate class, and then doing something like:

```
class WorkProjectSettings
{
    // specify which settings are allowed & should be present at WorkProject
    public $settings = [
        UsersCanAddCommentsToProject::class,
        UsersCanAddMediaToProject::class
    ];
}

class SchoolProjectSettings
{
    public $settings = [
        UsersCanAddCommentsToProject::class,
        ProjectIsEditableByUsers::class
    ];
}
```

In this case, instead of "settingType" classes I would implement SettingBoolType interface on given setting. But... what would be the best way to initialize a setting collection for each project, switch values (remember that front-end gives as an array, like "UsersCanAddCommentsToProject" => 1", so some kind of $key => $class map should be present?
Should I build some kind of factory, use IoC container for that? I am done with ideas :-/

cheers

Comment: How do you know it is a school project vs work project, type column on project or?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Project model has enum column 'type' among others.
I will correct that in the question, thanks!